# How to update json(one of the entry is list) in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I am new to Postgres JSON, I tried some quires but it doesn't work out.
I have a JSON in below format saved in DB. Now I have to write a update query (this will be executed during migration) to update value as follows.

1. if switches has displayName = "Name" it has to replaced by ProductName.
2. A new entry should be added to switchButtons in second index(for example). Entry is
   {
   "flex": 4,
   "name": "wwn",
   "tooltip": true,
   "isStatic": false,
   "selected": true,
   "sortable": true,
   "filterable": true,
   "displayName": "WWN"
   }

Main JSON saved in DB:

```
{
  "common": {
    "rightData": []
  },
  "tableCache": {
    "switches": [
      {
        "flex": 4,
        "name": "name",
        "route": true,
        "tooltip": true,
        "isStatic": true,
        "selected": true,
        "sortable": true,
        "sortIndex": 0,
        "sortOrder": "ASC",
        "filterable": true,
        "displayName": "Name"
      },
      {
        "flex": 4,
        "name": "type",
        "tooltip": true,
        "isStatic": false,
        "selected": true,
        "sortable": true,
        "filterable": true,
        "displayName": "Type"
      },
      {
        "flex": 4,
        "name": "logicalSwitchType",
        "tooltip": true,
        "isStatic": false,
        "selected": true,
        "sortable": true,
        "filterable": true,
        "displayName": "Logical Rate"
      }
    ],
    "switchButtons": [
      {
        "flex": 4,
        "name": "name",
        "route": true,
        "tooltip": true,
        "isStatic": true,
        "selected": true,
        "sortable": true,
        "sortIndex": 0,
        "sortOrder": "ASC",
        "filterable": true,
        "displayName": "Name"
      },
      {
        "flex": 4,
        "name": "type",
        "tooltip": true,
        "isStatic": false,
        "selected": true,
        "sortable": true,
        "filterable": true,
        "displayName": "Type"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Expected Result :

```
{
  "common": {
    "rightData": []
  },
  "tableCache": {
    "switches": [
      {
        "flex": 4,
        "name": "name",
        "route": true,
        "tooltip": true,
        "isStatic": true,
        "selected": true,
        "sortable": true,
        "sortIndex": 0,
        "sortOrder": "ASC",
        "filterable": true,
        **"displayName": "ProductName"**
      },
      {
        "flex": 4,
        "name": "type",
        "tooltip": true,
        "isStatic": false,
        "selected": true,
        "sortable": true,
        "filterable": true,
        "displayName": "Type"
      },
      {
        "flex": 4,
        "name": "logicalSwitchType",
        "tooltip": true,
        "isStatic": false,
        "selected": true,
        "sortable": true,
        "filterable": true,
        "displayName": "Logical Rate"
      }
    ],
    "switchButtons": [
      {
        "flex": 4,
        "name": "name",
        "route": true,
        "tooltip": true,
        "isStatic": true,
        "selected": true,
        "sortable": true,
        "sortIndex": 0,
        "sortOrder": "ASC",
        "filterable": true,
        "displayName": "Name"
      },
    **{
        "flex": 4,
        "name": "wwn",
        "tooltip": true,
        "isStatic": false,
        "selected": true,
        "sortable": true,
        "filterable": true,
        "displayName": "WWN"
      }**
      {
        "flex": 4,
        "name": "type",
        "tooltip": true,
        "isStatic": false,
        "selected": true,
        "sortable": true,
        "filterable": true,
        "displayName": "Type"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH updated_switches AS(
    SELECT id, json_agg(
        CASE WHEN element->>'displayName' = 'Name' THEN element || jsonb_build_object('displayName', 'WWN', 'name', 'wnn') ELSE element END
    ) res
    FROM your_table
        CROSS JOIN jsonb_path_query(json_field::jsonb, '$[*].tableCache.switches') switches
        CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(switches) element
    GROUP BY id
)
UPDATE your_table SET json_field = (json_field::jsonb) || jsonb_build_object('tableCache', jsonb_build_object('switches', res))
FROM updated_switches
WHERE your_table.id = updated_switches.id;
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but below are the points it is missing
1.This is removing the entire switchButtons from json
2. This is not replacing Name to ProductName, but with this I got some info